# Sequence / Series If and only If Proof

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I think I can prove the forwards direction but unsure about the reverse direction.

Prove that a sequence $a_n$ of real numbers converges if and only if the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n+1}-a_n$ converges.

$\implies$ Assume $a_n$ converges to a real number $l$, so for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $N \in \mathbb N$, such that $|a_n-l| < \epsilon$ for all $n>N$. Now consider the series of partial sums $\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_{n+1}-a_n$. This is a telescoping series - $\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_{n+1}-a_n = a_{N+1}-a_1$.

Since $N+1 > N$, by assumption, $a_{N+1}$ must be a real number and so is $a_1$, so $a_{N+1}-a_n$ must also be a real number, meaning series converges as sequence of partial sums converges to a real number $s$ (where $s := a_{N+1}-a_1$.)

$\leftarrow$ If the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n+1}-a_n$ converges, then the sequence of partial sums $\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_{n+1}-a_n$ converges to a real number $s$. So, $a_{N+1}-a_1 = s$......

Can I please have some help ?!

Comment: $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n+1}-a_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n -a_1$$

Comment: @Fix Thanks. Which direction of the proof is that for ? Do I need to change my forwards direction too ?

Comment: For the backwards direction. Though you can actually do both directions simultaneously: because of the above relation (my first comment), the convergence of the sum is equivalent to the convergence of the series, as $a_1$ is finite.

Comment: @Fix Was my forwards direction incorrect ?

Comment: Yes, it is correct, but not the nicest way